# Spring: Excluding injection of dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I know this is possible to exclude classes from a component-scan using exclude-filter .

The question is if it is possible to exclude the injection of a dependency in a class being injected.

For example, say I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactory
{
    @Resource
    private Service1 service1;

    @Resource
    private Service2 service2;

...

}
```

Now I would like to have ServiceFactory injected, service1 injected, but I would like to exclude service2 from the injection.

Of course I tried the following and it didn't work

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage">
    <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="...Service2" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: you can remove Service2  from scanning and put 
```@Autowired(required=false)
private Service2 service2;```

Comment: Thx. I am trying to do that in the context of a unit test, if I put required=false it will also not require injection at runtime in the real application which I am not interested in.

Comment: ohh, That means in your actual application you want this bean to be injected and only in the case of test you don't want this bean right? In that case you can create another bean which implements same interface as service2 (you may have to write that interface). And In the test case declare this new bean as @Primary, so that in test scope this bean will be picked. But your actual application will work as is.

Comment: Thx, This is an expensive solution though as this means i need to create such pair bean for a multitude of beans. There is no way you can do that in big applications with hundreds of beans.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case (where you don't want to inject in unit test, but want to inject in prod, but also don't want to create a dummy bean) you can use the [@MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation

I think this is a better solution than to just not inject the bean, becuase that way you avoid `NullPointerException`